# Game in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I know it is possible to create games using codename one, but I have a question about this.
I currently have a windows phone 7 game, which I want to recreate using codename one, but I am wondering about the efficiency of the platform. I am mostly concerned with lag issues, so I would like to know if anyone has experience in writing a game for codename one, where a bit more is going on than the card game displayed on their website.

I'm also interested in the mechanism, is it possible to use sprites?

So main questions:

- Performance? (Doesn't codename one use XNA as default renderer anyway?)
- Sprites?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Codename One probably isn't the right answer for you.

The Windows Phone port for 7.5 was based on XNA but since MS effectively killed that off we had to abandon that approach and MS didn't provide any alternative (Direct X without widgets isn't an alternative). So graphics on Windows Phone are currently drawn in a relatively in-efficient way which might work for a card game but not if you need faster performance.

Android/iOS performance should be good but Windows Phone will probably under perform until MS resolves this use case.

Codename One wasn't designed as a game platform initially so it doesn't have sprites and other game mainstays but it does have components and other elements you can use. See [my article for SDJ on creating a game with Codename One](http://sdjournal.org/game-development-how-to-become-a-millionaire-teaser-download-for-free/?utm_source=CodenameOne&utm_campaign=ccfb0e67f6-Codename_One_September_Newsletter_2013&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_961738d15f-ccfb0e67f6-63540153).

Comment: Thanks again Shai! Amazed by how you guys manage all that work + respond to user questions so quickly :)